TypeScript playground and TSX give different method decorator outputs
Consider the following code:
function decorate(target: any, context: any) {
    console.log("Method details:", {target, context});
}

class Example {
    @decorate
    public helloWorld() {
    }
}

When I run this in the TypeScript Playground, I get the following result:
[LOG]: "Method details:",  {
  "target": {},
  "context": "helloWorld"
}

However, when I run this with npx tsx example.ts, I get a different result:
Method details: {
  target: [Function: helloWorld],
  context: {
    kind: 'method',
    name: 'helloWorld',
    metadata: [Object: null prototype] {},
    addInitializer: [Function: addInitializer],
    static: false,
    private: false,
    access: { has: [Function (anonymous)], get: [Function (anonymous)] }
  }
}

What causes these outputs to be different, and why?

Different typescript versions and/or tsconfig values, probably? Please state what exactly you were using.

Are you familar with the NOTE at the top of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html? And in particular with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators?

There are two implementations of decorators. Which to use is governed by the experimentalDecorators compiler option.
You can toggle this in the playground by clicking "TS Config" and finding experimentalDecorators.
You probably want it disabled unless using a library that requires the experimental version of decorators, which are now considered "legacy" as of Typescript 5.0.

The linked article is really useful, thank you. Weirdly, the experimentalDectorators option was enabled in both places, and was using the same compiler version, so I'm still at a loss as to why the results were different.
